# How to use a Case When Statement to Count a Count Column

Tags: sql, case

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.location_name, COUNT (*) AS COUNT
FROM fastfood
GROUP BY f.location_name;
```

Hi, What I want to do is count the Count column, so I can see specifically how many locations have a count of one, how many locations have a count of 2, etc.
Can someone assist?
Thank you!

Comment: Why do you use `DISTINCT` here?

Comment: Can you give an example? How does a fast_food have two locations in the same place? And if they are not exactly in the same place, then what are you actually counting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT counter,count(*) how_many FROM (
  SELECT location_name, COUNT(*) AS COUNTER
  FROM fastfood 
  GROUP BY location_name
) a GROUP BY counter
```